# Turn off embedded Elasticsearch in Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

By default, Spring Boot will create an embedded Elasticsearch.  It can be turned off by setting spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes.  However, I'm not sure how to do this in a JUnit test.  For example, I have:

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(RemoteElasticsearch.class)
@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackageClasses = {
        }
)
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.me.repo")
public class RemoteElasticsearch {
    @Inject
    private SomeRepo someRepo;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        someRepo.save(new Something());
    }
}
```

It connects to the remote elasticsearch if I set the appropriate environment variable (eg spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-node=host:9300).  Can I somehow set this value directly on this test?

Answer (score 1):

Just create second `application.properties` file in `src/test/resources` with `spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes` disabled. Spring Boot will use this file instead PROD configuration from `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Would you please explain which parameter has to be set? I tryes "spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=''" with no success